# How can I remove the readonly attribute of a word document using c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using office 2013, and I used the code below to open a word document:

```
object fileName = FD.FileName;
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
WordApp.Visible = true;
aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing);
aDoc.Activate();
```

How can I enable editing for some **read only** word files opened in my c# application?

Comment: Would [File.SetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) do the trick?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen nothing happened. It's the same when I am trying to open it using c# it says Filename(Read Only)- Word. Yes it is opening ms office but not editable. I need to make it editable when opened using c#

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen or is it an issue on my ms office?

Comment: @RutherBergonia: How do you create the file? Programmatically? Is it a file downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: The file is selected thru the openFileDialog and I used interop services to open it thru ms word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's nothing to do with Office-interop, `ReadOnly` is a **file attribute** of that file. You could remove this by setting its `FileAttribute` to `FileAttributes.Normal` before you open the file.

You can try the code below:

```
string fileName = FD.FileName;
File.SetAttributes(fileName, FileAttributes.Normal);

aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, Visible: isVisible);
aDoc.Activate();
```

Remember, if you want to set it back to `ReadOnly` after you close the file, add the line below after you call `aDoc.Close()`:

```
File.SetAttributes(fileName, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: thanks! will try that later. haha I will have to focus more now on my printing issues haha. but anyways thans a lot man!